# C#: How to speed up my program for searching strong contiguous components in graph

Tags: c#

at school i get a task to create a program, which search for strong contiguous components in graph. My program gives correct output, but a program is slow. I cant get into global time requirement. Can somebody help me make a program faster? Thanks you all.

**Task:**
For a given set of web pages, we want to find largest subsets such that from every page in a subset you can follow links to any other page in the same subset.

*Input:*
On the first line, there are two numbers, number of the pages N, and total number of links M. Pages are numbered from 0 up to N-1. On lines 2 up to M+1, there are two numbers per line. The first is the source page and the second is the target page of a link.

*Output:*
On N lines there is a component ID for every single page. The componet ID is the smallest page index on the component.

*Time limits:*
Amount of data: 10000 -> max 0.2 seconds / Amount of data: 100000 -> max 2 seconds / Amount of data: 500000 -> max 10 seconds

**Examples:**

```
Input:              Input:
3 3                 3 3
0 1                 1 2
1 0                 2 1
1 2                 1 2

Output:             Output:
0                   0
0                   1
2                   1
```

**Program:**

Program is written in czech language, but i tried description it in english.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace tgh_web
    {
        class Vrchol //class Vertex
        {
            public int cislo_vrcholu;           //page ID (ID of vertex)
            public int cislo_komponenty;        //component ID where is page
            public bool prepsano = false;       //A flag that indicates whether the component ID has been overwritten by the smallest page ID on the component
            //for graph
            public int typ_vrcholu;             //vertex mark -> 0 - unvisited (white), 1 - visiting (gray), 2 - visited/locked (black)
            public List<int> sousedici_vrcholy; //neighbors of page (vertex), there is link between page (vertex) and neighbor from List
            public int pre_time, post_time;     //previsit time and postvisit time of vertex time (for DFS)
            //for transpose graph
            public int typ_vrcholu_trans;       //mark of vertex in transpose graph 
            public List<int> sousedici_vrcholy_trans; //neighbors of vertex in transpose graph
            public int pre_time_trans, post_time_trans; //previsit time and postvisit time of vertex in transpose graph (for DFS in transpose graph)
        }

        class Program
        {
            public static int time, time_trans;
            public static List<Vrchol> seznam_vrcholu; //list of vertices (pages)
            public static int komponenta = 0; //component number
            public static Stack<Vrchol> zasobnik; //stack
            public static List<int> vrcholy_komponenty; //list of vertices in this component

            //DFS in graph
            public static void DFS(Vrchol vrchol)
            {
                vrchol.typ_vrcholu = 1; //mark of vertex is set to 1 - visiting
                time = time + 1;
                vrchol.pre_time = time; //set previsit time of vertex
                zasobnik.Push(vrchol);
                List<Vrchol> list_sousedici_vrcholy = new List<Vrchol>();

                foreach (int index in vrchol.sousedici_vrcholy)                      
                    list_sousedici_vrcholy.Add(seznam_vrcholu.Find(x => x.cislo_vrcholu == index));            

                foreach (Vrchol v in list_sousedici_vrcholy)           
                    if (v.typ_vrcholu == 0)              
                        DFS(v);

                vrchol.typ_vrcholu = 2; //mark of vertex is set to 2 - visited/locked
                time = time + 1;
                vrchol.post_time = time;
                zasobnik.Pop();
                vrchol.cislo_komponenty = komponenta;

                if (zasobnik.Count == 0)         
                    komponenta++;           
            }

            //DFS in transpose graph
            public static void DFS_trans(Vrchol vrchol)
            {
                vrchol.typ_vrcholu_trans = 1;
                time_trans = time_trans + 1;
                vrchol.pre_time_trans = time_trans;
                List<Vrchol> list_sousedici_vrcholy_trans = new List<Vrchol>();

                foreach (int index in vrchol.sousedici_vrcholy_trans)  
                    list_sousedici_vrcholy_trans.Add(seznam_vrcholu.ElementAt(index));   

                foreach (Vrchol v in list_sousedici_vrcholy_trans)
                    if (v.typ_vrcholu_trans == 0)
                        DFS_trans(v);

                vrchol.typ_vrcholu_trans = 2;
                time_trans = time_trans + 1;
                vrchol.post_time_trans = time_trans;
            }

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int time, time_trans = 0;
                seznam_vrcholu = new List<Vrchol>();
                zasobnik  = new Stack<Vrchol>();
                vrcholy_komponenty = new List<int>();
                int pocet_vrcholu, pocet_hran, aktualni_hrana = 0; //number of vertex, number of links, actual_link is set to 0
                string prvni_radek, radek; //first row, next rows
                string[] casti_prv_radku, casti_radku; //parts of firts row, parts of next rows
                int hrana_out, hrana_in; //links

                //loading first row - input (first row - number of pages(vertices) + total number of links)
                prvni_radek = Console.ReadLine();            
                casti_prv_radku = prvni_radek.Split(' ');     
                int.TryParse(casti_prv_radku[0], out pocet_vrcholu);    
                int.TryParse(casti_prv_radku[1], out pocet_hran);       

                //creating vertex
                for (int i = 0; i < pocet_vrcholu; i++)
                {
                    Vrchol v = new Vrchol();                       
                    v.cislo_vrcholu = i;        //id of vertex = i                   
                    v.typ_vrcholu = 0;          //mark of vertex set to 0 - unvisited                   
                    v.typ_vrcholu_trans = 0;    //mark of vertex in transpose graph set to 0                  
                    v.sousedici_vrcholy = new List<int>();
                    v.sousedici_vrcholy_trans = new List<int>();
                    seznam_vrcholu.Insert(i, v);
                }

                //loading next rows - input (on a row is the source page and the target page of a link
                while (aktualni_hrana < pocet_hran) //actual_link < total number of links
                {
                    radek = Console.ReadLine();
                    casti_radku = radek.Split(' ');
                    int.TryParse(casti_radku[0], out hrana_out);
                    int.TryParse(casti_radku[1], out hrana_in);
//targed page, where link goes in (hrana_in), add to the list of neighbors (sousedici_vrcholy) that belongs to source page, where link goes out (hrana_out)
                    seznam_vrcholu.ElementAt(hrana_out).sousedici_vrcholy.Add(hrana_in);                      
//It is the same, but pages (vertex) are swaped (to create a transpose graph)
                    seznam_vrcholu.ElementAt(hrana_in).sousedici_vrcholy_trans.Add(hrana_out);
                    aktualni_hrana++;
                }

                //DFS in transpose graph
                foreach (Vrchol v in seznam_vrcholu)          
                    if (v.typ_vrcholu_trans == 0)
                        DFS_trans(v);              


                //top sorting by postvisit time in transpose graph
                seznam_vrcholu.Sort(delegate(Vrchol x, Vrchol y)
                {
                    if (x.post_time_trans == null && y.post_time_trans == null) return 0;
                    else if (x.post_time_trans == null) return -1;
                    else if (y.post_time_trans == null) return 1;
                    else return y.post_time_trans.CompareTo(x.post_time_trans);
                });

                //DFS in graph, where vertices are sorted
                foreach(Vrchol v in seznam_vrcholu)
                    if (v.typ_vrcholu == 0)
                        DFS(v);

                //overwriting component ID  
                //the componet ID is the smallest page index on the component
                for (int i = 0; i < komponenta; i++ )
                {
                    vrcholy_komponenty.Clear();

                    foreach(Vrchol v in seznam_vrcholu)                   
                        if(v.cislo_komponenty == i && v.prepsano == false)
                            vrcholy_komponenty.Add(v.cislo_vrcholu);

                    int min = vrcholy_komponenty.ElementAt(0);

                    foreach(int cislo_vrcholu in vrcholy_komponenty)
                        if(cislo_vrcholu < min)
                            min = cislo_vrcholu;

                    //overwriting component ID and setting overwritten flag (v.prepsano) as true
                    foreach (Vrchol v in seznam_vrcholu)
                        if (v.cislo_komponenty == i && v.prepsano == false)
                        {
                            v.cislo_komponenty = min;
                            v.prepsano = true;
                        }
                }

                 //output
                 for (int j = 0; j < pocet_vrcholu; j++)
                     Console.WriteLine(seznam_vrcholu.Find(x => x.cislo_vrcholu == j).cislo_komponenty);

            Console.ReadKey();
            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use depth first search? Depending on the tree structure you may find breadth first search will be quicker. If it's shallow but wide BFS will be better. Deep but narrow, DFS will be better.

Comment: Thank for react. I can use only DFS. Maybe it will be a problem with using List<>, teacher thinks that Array will be faster than List, because accessing an element by index is in Array O(1) and in List is O(n), but we dont know if it is true.

Comment: Yea the next thing I was going to suggest was looking at your data structures. I'm struggling a bit to read the code because I can't keep all the czech variable names in my head ;-) 

Do you have open and closed set? Try using a priority queue for open set and hash set for closed set. Using array will be better than list, your teacher is correct.

You know you could use scientific method approach to validate what your teacher said? Substitute list for array and measure time taken to execute with different input sizes and graph it out.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to remake it to Array. :)